# How to generate <content:encoded> element in a RSS 2.0 feed using RSS:Maker?

Tags: ruby, rss

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 RSS::Maker module to generate a RSS 2.0 feed for a podcast.  I'd like to start including a `<content:encoded>` element for show notes.  This is my code for generating the RSS.

```ruby
s3_bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find(options[:bucket])

content = RSS::Maker.make(version) do |m|
        m.channel.title = options[:title]
        m.channel.link = options[:link]
        m.channel.description = options[:desc]
        m.channel.language = options[:language]
        m.channel.itunes_image = options[:image]
        m.items.do_sort = true

        s3_bucket.select{|object| object.key =~ /[\s\w]+\.(m4b|mp3|m4a|ogg|aac)/}.each do |audio|
                i = m.items.new_item
                i.link = audio.url(:authenticated => false)  
                i.title = audio.key.split(".")[0]
                i.author = options[:author]
                i.pubDate = audio.last_modified
                i.guid.content = audio.etag
                i.enclosure.url = i.link
                i.enclosure.length = audio.content_length
                i.enclosure.type = audio.content_type
                # Insert content:encoded code here
  end 
end
```

For generating the `<content:encoded>` element I've tried:

`i.encoded :content audio.metadata[:content]`

`i.encoded :content, audio.metadata[:content]`

`i.content = audio.metadata[:content]`

`i.content.encoded = audio.metadata[:content]`

`i.encoded = audio.metadata[:content]`

`i.encoded.content = audio.metadata[:content]`

None of these work and most throw a NoSuchMethod exception - which is not surprising based on the documentation of the RSS::Maker module.

Is there a way using RSS::Maker to add arbitrary elements with a namespace?

Comment: I accomplished what I wanted using `i.description = audio.metadata[:content]` but, I'm still curious what the answer to my question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re looking for `i.content_encoded`.

The documentation isn’t too great, so I used `i.methods` to get a list of methods I can use on feed items. `methods` works on all objects.

The list is quite long, so you most likely only want to show methods you can write to, i.e. something like this:

```
RSS::Maker.make("2.0") do |ma|
  puts ma.items.new_item.methods.keep_if { |m|
    m.to_s.end_with?("=")
  }.join("\n")
end
```